# Let $G$ be a group and let $H\le G$. Prove that for all $x \in G$, we have that $xHx^{−1 }= \{xax^{−1} ∶ a \in H\}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Tags: group-theory

Maybe I show $H$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$?

Comment: You’re making it much too hard: it has nothing to do with Sylow subgroups. Just check that $xHx^{-1}$ has the required properties.

Comment: Thanks I definitely figured I was making it hard. For some reason I thought this was in the chapter with Sylow subgroups but its just checking the regular subgroup criterion.

Comment: Since conjugation $\phi(a) =xax^{-1}$ is a homomorphism $H \to G$ we see that $xHx^{-1} = \phi(H)$ is a subgroup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$H$ will not in general be a Sylow $p$-subgroup.

We resolve the problem as follows. Let $x\in G$ and $H\leq G$. We take $P=xHx^{-1}$. Claim that $P\leq G$. Clearly $P$ is nonempty, since $xex^{-1}=e\in P$. Let $xax^{-1},xbx^{-1}\in P$. Observe that

$$\begin{align}
xax^{-1}(xbx^{-1})^{-1}&=xax^{-1}(bx^{-1})^{-1}x^{-1}\\
&=xax^{-1}(x^{-1})^{-1}b^{-1}x^{-1}\\
&=xax^{-1}xb^{-1}x^{-1}\\
&=xab^{-1}x^{-1}\\
&\in P.
\end{align}$$

So this concludes by the one step subgroup test.

Comment: Thanks guys. I think I was too in my head thinking about the chapter I am in about Sylow subgroups. I should have just followed the instinct how to check for a plain old subgroup.